# npm install jasmine-jquery fails

Tags: node.js, npm, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

Running `npm install jasmine-jquery` gives the error output seen below.
I'm running Windows 7. Any ideas?

```
npm install jasmine-jquery
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-jquery
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-jquery
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jsdom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jsdom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cssom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlparser
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cssom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlparser
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify

> contextify@0.0.7 preinstall C:\node\node_modules\jasmine-jquery\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify
> node-waf clean || (exit 0); node-waf configure build

Oväntat node-waf.
npm ERR! error installing contextify@0.0.7
npm ERR! error installing jsdom@0.2.10
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\node\node_modules\jasmine-jquery\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\___htmlparser.npm\package\runtests.min.js'
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "jasmine-jquery"
npm ERR! cwd C:\node\messagemetrics
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.6
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.0-beta-4
npm ERR! path C:\node\node_modules\jasmine-jquery\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\___htmlparser.npm\package\runtests.min.js
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\node\node_modules\jasmine-jquery\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\___htmlparser.npm\package\runtests.min.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! message ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\node\node_modules\jasmine-jquery\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\___htmlparser.npm\package\runtests.min.js'
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:204:26)
npm ERR! error rolling back jsdom@0.2.10 Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error 'C:\node\node_modules\jasmine-jquery\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\___request.npm\package\tests'
npm ERR! error installing jasmine-jquery@1.3.3
npm ERR! error rolling back jasmine-jquery@1.3.3 Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error 'C:\node\node_modules\jasmine-jquery\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\___request.npm\package'
npm ERR! contextify@0.0.7 preinstall: `node-waf clean || (exit 0); node-waf configure build`
npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node-waf clean || (exit 0); node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the contextify@0.0.7 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the contextify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-waf clean || (exit 0); node-waf configure build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls contextify
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "jasmine-jquery"
npm ERR! cwd C:\node\messagemetrics
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.6
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.0-beta-4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! message contextify@0.0.7 preinstall: `node-waf clean || (exit 0); node-waf configure build`
npm ERR! message `cmd "/c" "node-waf clean || (exit 0); node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\node\messagemetrics\npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Comment: https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/2061

" This is a jsdom bug. It should list contextify as an optionalDependency, or not use it at all. node-waf will never work on windows. "

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using sudo? 
This worked for me: sudo npm install jasmine-jquery, let me know if this works for you.

Comment: OP says he is using Windows 7